# ASP, MySQL and UTF-8

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, utf-8, odbc

First of all, I've read almost all topics about this. I've tried all advices but I couldn't solve this problem.

Here is the thing. I use Classic ASP and MySQL for a project. Everything just fine. If I write (an example) Response.Write("ĞŞÜÇÖİ") it works like a charm. But if that string comes from database, I see "ÄÅÃœÃ‡Ã–Ä°" instead of "ĞŞÜÇÖİ". When I look this with phpMyAdmin it's ok.

I use Dreamweaver CS6. I save all pages Unicode (UTF-8). I've written Session.CodePage = 65001, Response.CodePage = 65001, Response.Charset = "utf-8" in an include file that every page has it at the top. I've written meta charset utf-8. I use ODBC 5.2 x64 driver and my connection string has charset:UTF8;. And all MySQL settings utf-8 (tables, fields, everything).

Well I don't want to use other encodings, charsets. What am I doing doing wrong? It seems, it's about database. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the character set in the connection string using the charset parameter; see the [MySQL ODBC doco](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-odbc-configuration-connection-parameters.html). e.g. add <strike>"charset=utf8;"</strike> "charset=ucs2;" to your connection string.

Edited: I finally got a chance to run a simple test harness on this, and it does indeed fail with charset=utf8. However, since VBScript is running internally with UCS2, I gave it a try with charset=ucs2 and it works fine. NB: page is still set to send all output as UTF-8, it's just that VBScript is pulling data from an ODBC connection using UCS2. Job is done :)

Comment: I use this connection string: `Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=localhost;charset=UTF8;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;Option=3;`. But problem is the same.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website? It could be that the page isn't being served as UTF-8 as you think, due to another problem (e.g. output before your includes take effect). I generally start every ASP page with this snippet to ensure the correct codepage: `<%@ language="vbscript" codepage=65001 %>`. Also, are you sure the data in the database was correctly inserted as UTF-8? It's possible that the data itself is corrupted; check in a non-web client (like MySQL Workbench).

Comment: I can't provide a link. I'm working on localhost. Sorry for that. I've checked it with MySQL Workbench and everything is fine. I think it's about connection.

Comment: Yes, this is it! charset=ucs2 on connection string works. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: you saved me!
small update: ODBC 5.2w  is now called ODBC 5.2 UNICODE DRIVER.
Trying to used UCS2 for ODBC 5.2 ANSI driver didn't work. so pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

Even your connection should be UTF8. run this query before you run other queries

```
set names 'utf8'
```

> SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL
>   statements to the server. Thus, SET NAMES 'cp1251' tells the server,
>   “future incoming messages from this client are in character set
>   cp1251.” It also specifies the character set that the server should
>   use for sending results back to the client. (For example, it indicates
>   what character set to use for column values if you use a SELECT
>   statement.)

A SET NAMES 'x' statement is equivalent to these three statements:

```
SET character_set_client = x;
SET character_set_results = x;
SET character_set_connection = x;
```

FYI: [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: Well I tried "SET NAMES 'utf8'" with ODBC 5.2 but it says "SET NAMES not allowed by driver". When I change it to 3.51 nothing changes and when I try to save something it says "Incorrect string value: '\xC7\xC7\xC7' for column 'name' at row 1". I also tried "SET character_set_x" things but nothing changes.