# Emoji data retrieved via ODBC Connection appears as question mark

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, odbc

I connect to MySQL version 5.5.50-log from classic ASP pages.

The MySQL Database is set up as follows:

- Database charset: utf8mb4
- Database collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

The table and field:

- Character Set: utf8mb4
- Collation: utf8mb4_general_ci

To test, I have data in the table, which contains this string: **(T_T) é, è, à, ç**

This is a screenshot of the data from the SQLyog:

[image]

This is my test web page:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Pasted directly from database field: (T_T) é, è, à, ç</p>
  <p>Returned from SQL statement: ?(T_T) é, è, à, ç</p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

The issue is not that emoji data cannot be displayed on the web page, as the directly pasted content from MySQL appears fine. The issue is that once the data is returned from an SQL Select from MySQL via the ODBC Driver, it does not render correctly.

I have the following set in the ASP code:

```
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

I have tried other variations - e.g.

```
Response.CodePage = 1252
Response.LCID = 1060
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
```

But they made no difference.

I have tried a range of MySQL ODBC Drivers - e.g.

```
''----------------------
''connection string
''----------------------

Dim oConn
set oConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
'oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=mydb; User=root; Password=testing; Option=3; CharSet=utf8mb4; stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';"
```

That doesn't work...

I have tried using a System DSN instead using these drivers:

- MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
- MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver
- MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver

None of them solve the issue.

I wondered if there is any way around this, or if there is basically no way to display emoji data that is retrieved from a MySQL database using Classic ASP?

As far as I know, from reading elsewhere, the MySQL database is set up correctly, in a way which supports storing emoji characters, confirmed by the fact I can view it stored in the database without an issue. It's just when I try and pull it out of the database via the Classic ASP to MySQL connection that the emoji character is not displayed.

Edit - the ASP page itself is saved as a UTF-8 encoded file:

[image]

Comment: Using `Response` alone is not enough, the ASP page needs to be saved in the correct encoding and IIS has to be told to read it as UTF-8. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914278/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart - thanks for your reply. The page is saved as UTF-8, I have added a screenshot to confirm as an edit at the end of my question.

Comment: Would recommend going through [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34356187/692942) and checking each on off. If after following these it still doesn’t work I would look at the driver you are using as well.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart - I have set this at the very top of the page: `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` and set the response.codepage and charset as per your advice on the answers you've linked to. No joy. I've tried ODBC 8, 5.1 and 3.51, none of them do the trick. I've tried connection string methods, and using a System DNS with Charset set and initial statement set to `set names utf8mb4` or `set names 'utf8mb4'`, nothing works... I think I'll have to give it up!

Comment: Sorry to hear that, it does sound as it maybe a MySQL Driver issue but I don’t have enough experience using MySQL to best advise. But maybe [this will help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14015499/692942), good luck.

Comment: @4532066 I'm having exactly the same problem and I've gone through all the suggested solutions, but even if the data is stored correctly in the db (Driver 8.0 UNICODE), when asp retrieves it, it shows only a "??" for each emoji. Have you found a solution? :/

Comment: @Fehu I never got it working. In the end I used PHP for the pages where I needed to extract data that might include emoji data. Sorry I have no solution.

Answer (score 1):

On top of setting the responses and saving the file as UTF-8, you may also need to set the page language like this. Note that this should be at the very top of the file before anything else:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
response.codepage = 65001
response.charset = "utf-8"
%>
```

I've fought a lot with encoding and half our system is made up of non-UTF files and this code right here is what has made me able to work with UTF-8 for my own functions.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a MySQL/MariaDB database fully in `utf8mb4` with collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, there is a bug in a lot of ODBC drivers preventing to **READ BACK DATA**, making out-of-BMP characters (like Emoji) appear as question marks. Such bugs are referenced here :

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104346
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69021

Here are 2 possible solutions to finally READ back Emojis from database, in Classic ASP (but can apply to other languages) :

1. Run MySQL v8 and upgrade to ODBC Connector 8.0.27 at least.
   Before this ODBC version, the bug is still here, and as stated by MySQL, the ODBC connector (even in version 8) does not allow `SET NAMES ...` in the initial statement, making it impossible to use `initstmt=set names 'utf8mb4'` in the connection string as a workaround.
2. Run MariaDB 10.3 +.
   Conversely to MySQL, MariaDB *DOES* allows `SET NAMES ...` in the initial statement ! **That's great**, because you can now use `initstmt=set names 'utf8mb4';charset=utf8` (yes, do not specify *utf8mb4* here as the charset, but use *utf8* instead, as this encoding is used as the transport character set to communicate with the server).
   Use the MariaDB ODBC 3.1.20 Driver.
   And obviously, as stated by [**Mighty Chaffinch** in this thread](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#comment-65), your ASP page must be saved as UTF-8 in your text editor, and need to include :

```
Session.CodePage = 65001;
Response.ContentType = "text/HTML";
Response.CodePage = 65001;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
```

Happy Classic ASP !